# Binary variables in time series: integer linear programming

Tags: linear-programming, binary, integer-programming, time-series, constraints

I'm working on a problem and I can't seem to find an easy solution to it. It's about an optimization problem, concerning a time series.

I have a binary variable $\alpha_t$ for $t \in [0, 24[$. I also have an extra constraint, which states that $$\sum_{t=0}^{23} \alpha_t  \geq 14.$$ The problem is that I want to add an extra constraint that if a certain $\alpha_t = 1$, then either $$\alpha_{t-1} = \alpha_{t+1} = 1$$ or $$\alpha_{t-1} = \alpha_{t-2} = 1$$ or $$\alpha_{t+1} = \alpha_{t+2} = 1, $$ i.e. at least 3 consecutive times $\alpha$ needs to be 1. It can be 4 times, it can be 5, but it has to be at least 3 times.

The most intuitive idea is probably this:
$$\alpha_t = 1 \Rightarrow \alpha_t + \alpha_{t+1} + \alpha_{t + 2} = 3,$$ but from a certain $t$, this will result that all $\alpha_t = 1$.

I also tried big M constraints, but for larger consecutive times ( $\geq 3)$, this becomes almost impossible to write down/implement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One simple way to enforce a run length of at least three, is to forbid patterns `010` and `0110`. This can be modeled as:

$$ -x_t + x_{t+1} - x_{t+2} \le 0 $$

and

$$ -x_t + x_{t+1} + x_{t+2} - x_{t+3} \le 1 $$

A little bit of thought is needed to decide what to do at the borders, especially the first time period.

A different approach is detailed [here](https://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2018/03/production-scheduling-minimum-up-time.html).

Comment: I thought about that too, but what about patterns like 110, 101, 011, etc? I want to generalize the method and I feel like this would get way out of hand way too soon for larger consecutive times.

Comment: I don't think you fully understand what I suggested. You really only need to worry about 010 and 0110. (With some more thought needed near the boundaries of the planning period)

Comment: that indeed seemed to be the case. Smart observation regarding the patterns!

Comment: Not so smart. This is a fairly standard and often used approach. Most modelers are well aware of this.

Comment: Apologies, novice modeler here. Small follow-up question: is there then also a way to formulate the constraint, that if one $x_t=1$ in an interval $[a, b]$, then *all* $x_t$ in $[a, b] $ have to be equal to 1? (Without using Big-$M$ constraints?)

Comment: This is somewhat unrelated but actually trivial. This means all $x_t$ in the interval are all 0 or all 1. This should be easy to model.

Comment: Yes, I tried it with Big-$M$ constraints, but they don't seem to integrate well within the rest of the model, unfortunately.

Comment: No big-Ms needed. There is basically just one binary decision for all $t \in [a,b]$. Or in different words: $x_a=x_{a+1}=\dots=x_{b}$.

Comment: Oh my, that's... embarrassing. -.- 
Thanks for the continued help!

Answer (score 1):

One method is to let $x_t$ denote the starting indices and $y_t$ denote the ending indices of the sequences of ones. For example, if $x=(0,1,0,0,0,1,0)$ and $y=(0,0,0,1,0,0,1)$, the sequence is $\alpha=(0,1,1,1,0,1,1)$. You get the following constraints:

1. number of starting indices equals number of ending indices:
   $$\sum_t x_t = \sum_t y_t$$
2. cannot end a sequence unless it was started at least 3 periods prior:
   $$y_i \leq \sum_{t=1}^{i-2}x_t-y_t \quad \forall i$$
3. cannot start a new sequence before the previous one is closed:
   $$x_i \leq 1- \sum_{t=1}^{i-1}(x_t-y_t) \quad \forall i$$
4. relating $\alpha$ to $x,y$:
   $$\alpha_i = \sum_{t=1}^{i}x_t - \sum_{t=1}^{i-1}y_t \quad \forall i$$

Comment: I think there's an error in your reasoning: when I implement this, I get only one $x_t = 1$, which results in some $\alpha = (0, 0, \ldots, 0, 1, 1, \ldots , 1)$. In every case I tried (also by forcing some values of variables), it's as if there's a value of 1 in $\alpha$, so must be everything else after that.

Comment: @Riley you are right, I have corrected the errors.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, this doesn't necessarily guarantee consecutiveness. Formulation nr 2 doesn't rule out the possibility of a 'zero gap'. Example: $\alpha = (1,1,1,0,1),  x=(1,0,0,0,1),  y=(0,0,1,0,1)$

Comment: @Riley the second constraint includes $y_5 \leq x_1+x_2+x_3 - y_1 - y_2 - y_3$, which in your example is $y_5 \leq 0$, so $y_5=1$ is infeasible

Answer (score 1):

Reading your question I think that you want

$$\alpha_t = 1 \implies \alpha_{t+1} + \alpha_{t+2} = 2 \vee \alpha_{t-1} + \alpha_{t+1} = 2 \vee \alpha_{t-2} + \alpha_{t-1} = 2$$

not

$$\alpha_t = 1 \implies \alpha_t + \alpha_{t+1} + \alpha_{t + 2} = 3, ~ \forall t\in [0, n-2]$$

or, equivalently,

$$\alpha_t = 1 \implies \alpha_{t+1} + \alpha_{t + 2} = 2, ~ \forall t\in [0, n-2]$$

In this case, the answer should be

$$ \alpha_t  \implies \alpha_{t+1} \wedge \alpha_{t + 2}, ~ \forall t\in [0, n-2]$$

$$ \neg\alpha_t  \vee (\alpha_{t+1} \wedge \alpha_{t + 2}), ~ \forall t\in [0, n-2]$$

$$ (\neg\alpha_t  \vee \alpha_{t+1}) \wedge (\neg\alpha_t \vee \alpha_{t + 2}), ~ \forall t\in [0, n-2]$$

rewriting this sentence in binary variables, the constraints are

$$
\begin{align}
(1-\alpha_t) + \alpha_{t+1} \geq 1, ~ \forall t\in [0, n-2]\\
(1-\alpha_t) + \alpha_{t+2} \geq 1, ~ \forall t\in [0, n-2]
\end{align}
$$

**Another case**

OK, consider this logical sentence

$$\alpha_t \implies (\alpha_{t+1} \wedge \alpha_{t+2}) \vee (\alpha_{t-1} \wedge \alpha_{t+1}) \vee (\alpha_{t-2} \wedge \alpha_{t-1})$$

$$\neg\alpha_t \vee (\alpha_{t+1} \wedge \alpha_{t+2}) \vee (\alpha_{t-1} \wedge \alpha_{t+1}) \vee (\alpha_{t-2} \wedge \alpha_{t-1})$$

After some operations ...

$$(\neg\alpha_t \vee \alpha_{t-2} \vee \alpha_{t+1}) \wedge (\neg\alpha_t \vee \alpha_{t-1} \vee \alpha_{t+1}) \wedge (\neg\alpha_t \vee \alpha_{t-1} \vee \alpha_{t+2})$$

the constraints for $t\in [2, n-2]$ are

$$
\begin{align}
(1-\alpha_t) + \alpha_{t-2} + \alpha_{t+1} \geq 1 \\
(1-\alpha_t) + \alpha_{t-1} + \alpha_{t+1} \geq 1 \\
(1-\alpha_t) + \alpha_{t-1} + \alpha_{t+2} \geq 1 
\end{align}
$$

You need to fix the cases $t=0, t=1, t=n-1, t=n$ using the same idea. For $t\in\{0,n\}$ you can use the first set of equations presented in this text.

$$
\begin{align}
(1-\alpha_0) + \alpha_{1} \geq 1 \\
(1-\alpha_0) + \alpha_{2} \geq 1 \\
(1-\alpha_n) + \alpha_{n-1} \geq 1 \\
(1-\alpha_n) + \alpha_{n-2} \geq 1
\end{align}
$$

For $t\in\{1,n-1\}$

$$\alpha_1 \implies (\alpha_{2} \wedge \alpha_{3}) \vee (\alpha_{0} \wedge \alpha_{2})$$

$$\neg\alpha_1 \vee (\alpha_{2} \wedge \alpha_{3}) \vee (\alpha_{0} \wedge \alpha_{2}) $$

$$(\neg\alpha_1 \vee \alpha_{0} \vee \alpha_{3}) \wedge (\neg\alpha_{1} \wedge \alpha_{2}) $$

and

$$\alpha_{n-1} \implies (\alpha_{n-2} \wedge \alpha_{n-3}) \vee (\alpha_{n} \wedge \alpha_{n-2})$$

$$\neg\alpha_{n-1} \vee (\alpha_{n-2} \wedge \alpha_{n-3}) \vee (\alpha_{n} \wedge \alpha_{n-2}) $$

$$(\neg\alpha_{n-1} \vee \alpha_{n} \vee \alpha_{n-3}) \wedge (\neg\alpha_{n-1} \wedge \alpha_{n-2}) $$

resulting in these constraints

$$
\begin{align}
(1-\alpha_1) + \alpha_{0} + \alpha_{3}\geq 1 \\
(1-\alpha_1) + \alpha_{2} \geq 1 \\
(1-\alpha_{n-1}) + \alpha_{n} +\alpha_{n-3} \geq 1 \\
(1-\alpha_{n-1}) + \alpha_{n-2} \geq 1
\end{align}
$$

finally

$$
\left\{\begin{align}
& (1-\alpha_0) + \alpha_{1} \geq 1 & \\
& (1-\alpha_0) + \alpha_{2} \geq 1 & \\
& (1-\alpha_1) + \alpha_{0} + \alpha_{3}\geq 1 & \\
& (1-\alpha_1) + \alpha_{2} \geq 1 & \\
& (1-\alpha_t) + \alpha_{t-2} + \alpha_{t+1} \geq 1, & \forall t\in [2,n-2] \\
& (1-\alpha_t) + \alpha_{t-1} + \alpha_{t+1} \geq 1, & \forall t\in [2,n-2] \\
& (1-\alpha_t) + \alpha_{t-1} + \alpha_{t+2} \geq 1, & \forall t\in [2,n-2] \\ 
& (1-\alpha_{n-1}) + \alpha_{n} +\alpha_{n-3} \geq 1 & \\
& (1-\alpha_{n-1}) + \alpha_{n-2} \geq 1 & \\
& (1-\alpha_n) + \alpha_{n-1} \geq 1 & \\
& (1-\alpha_n) + \alpha_{n-2} \geq 1 &
\end{align}\right.
$$

These constraints cover all cases correctly. There is no counterexample.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've got it:

use the reasoning in this post [Integer linear programming constraint for maximum number of consecutive ones in a binary sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2178930/integer-linear-programming-constraint-for-maximum-number-of-consecutive-ones-in?rq=1).
Here, we have to look at the $\alpha_t$ as zero's instead of ones. At this point, you can impose a maximum of consecutive zero's.

If the variable however has a value of one, then you can use big M constraints to set the sum of the next 3, equal to 3.

Comment: You want to impose a minimum number of consecutive ones, so that reasoning does not apply. Using big-M is not necessary, see my other answer.